# "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fields_view_get'". How to resolve this error in Odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, xlwt

I was trying to develop excel reports using xlwt. Unfortunately I am getting following error i.e "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fields_view_get'" from  the following code:

Xlwt report code in odoo v8.

excel file generation using xlwt.

```
import xlwt
from StringIO import StringIO
import base64
from datetime import datetime
from xlwt import Workbook,easyxf
from openerp import models, fields, api

class all_invoice_wizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'all.invoice.wizard'

    from_date = fields.Date('From Date', help='Select Start Date')
    to_date = fields.Date('To Date', help='Select End Date')

    def initialize_report(self, data):
        '''This method initializes the excel report'''
        fl = StringIO()
        wbk = xlwt.Workbook(encoding = 'utf-8')
        sheet = wbk.add_sheet('Sheet 1',cell_overwrite_ok=True)
        return fl,wbk,sheet

    def generate_xlwt_report_file(self, report_name, fl, wbk, sheet):
            '''This method generates the report file.'''
            wbk.save(fl)
            fl.seek(0)
            buf = base64.encodestring(fl.read())
            ctx = dict(self._context)
            ctx.update({'file': buf, 'report_name': report_name})
            try:
                form_id = self.env['ir.model.data'].get_object_reference('account', 'wiz_excel_file_download_form_view')[1]
            except ValueError:
                form_id = False
            return {
                        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
                        'view_type': 'form',
                        'view_mode': 'form',
                        'res_model': 'wizard.excel.report.file',
                        'views': [(form_id, 'form')],
                        'view_id': form_id,
                        'target': 'new',
                        'context': ctx,
                    }

    @api.multi
    def print_invoice(self):
        data = self.read()[0]
        ctx = self._context

        #Initialize the Report
        fl,wbk,sheet = self.initialize_report(data)

        #Report Formatting
        bold_center = xlwt.easyxf('font: bold 1; align: vert centre, horiz center')
        sheet.header_str = 'Invoice Report: '+self.from_date+' - '+self.to_date

        sheet.col(2).width = 6000
        sheet.col(3).width = 5000
        sheet.col(5).width = 7000
        sheet.col(7).width = 7000

        #Report Heading
        sheet.write(0, 0, "Sl No", bold_center)
        sheet.write(0, 1, "Invoice No.", bold_center)
        sheet.write(0, 2, "Date", bold_center)
        sheet.write(0, 3, "Location", bold_center)
        sheet.write(0, 4, "Taxable Value", bold_center)
        sheet.write(0, 5, "SGST", bold_center)
        sheet.write(0, 6, "CGST", bold_center)
        sheet.write(0, 7, "IGST", bold_center)
        sheet.write(0, 8, "Total Taxes", bold_center)
        sheet.write(0, 9, "TCS", bold_center)
        sheet.write(0, 10, "Total Invoice Value", bold_center)



        #Report Data
        invoice_data = self.env['account.invoice'].search([('date_invoice','>=',self.from_date),('date_invoice','<=',self.to_date)])
        if invoice_data:

            bulk_invoice_data = []
            for test in invoice_data:
                single_invoice_data = []
                single_invoice_data.append(test.number)
                single_invoice_data.append(test.date_invoice)
                single_invoice_data.append(test.issuing.name)
                single_invoice_data.append(test.amount_untaxed)
                for invoice_computation_lines in test.tax_line:
                    if 'SGST' in invoice_computation_lines.name:
                        single_invoice_data.append(invoice_computation_lines.amount)
            else:
            single_invoice_data.append(0.00)


            if 'CGST' in invoice_computation_lines.name:
                        single_invoice_data.append(invoice_computation_lines.amount)
            else:
            single_invoice_data.append(0.00)


            if 'IGST' in invoice_computation_lines.name:
                        single_invoice_data.append(invoice_computation_lines.amount)
            else:
            single_invoice_data.append(0.00)

                single_invoice_data.append(test.amount_tax)
        single_invoice_data.append(test.comment)
        single_invoice_data.append(test.amount_total)
                bulk_invoice_data.append(single_invoice_data)

            row_count = 1
            for single_invoice in bulk_invoice_data:
                    sheet.write(row_count, 0, row_count)
                    sheet.write(row_count, 1, single_invoice[0])
                    sheet.write(row_count, 2, single_invoice[1])
                    sheet.write(row_count, 3, single_invoice[2])
            sheet.write(row_count, 4, single_invoice[3])
                    sheet.write(row_count, 5, single_invoice[4])
                    sheet.write(row_count, 6, single_invoice[5])
                    sheet.write(row_count, 7, single_invoice[6])
                    '''sheet.write(row_count, 8, single_invoice[7])
                    sheet.write(row_count, 9, single_invoice[8])
                    sheet.write(row_count, 10, single_invoice[9])'''

                    row_count += 1
        return self.generate_xlwt_report_file('Invoice Report.xls', fl, wbk, sheet)
```

I guess this is the part where I have gone wrong

```
 def generate_xlwt_report_file(self, report_name, fl, wbk, sheet):
            '''This method generates the report file.'''
            wbk.save(fl)
            fl.seek(0)
            buf = base64.encodestring(fl.read())
            ctx = dict(self._context)
            ctx.update({'file': buf, 'report_name': report_name})
            try:
                form_id = self.env['ir.model.data'].get_object_reference('account', 'wiz_excel_file_download_form_view')[1]
            except ValueError:
                form_id = False
            return {
                        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
                        'view_type': 'form',
                        'view_mode': 'form',
                        'res_model': 'wizard.excel.report.file',
                        'views': [(form_id, 'form')],
                        'view_id': form_id,
                        'target': 'new',
                        'context': ctx,
                    }
```

Error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/administrator/odoo_ext/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 537, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/administrator/odoo_ext/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 574, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/administrator/odoo_ext/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 310, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/administrator/odoo_ext/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/administrator/odoo_ext/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 307, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/administrator/odoo_ext/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 803, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/administrator/odoo_ext/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 403, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/administrator/odoo_ext/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 944, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/administrator/odoo_ext/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fields_view_get'
```

Unfortunately no trace of line numbers.

Any help to correct where I have went wrong would be really helpful.

Comment: can you share minimum non working snippet ?

Comment: @Mahesh, you mean non working part of the code?

Comment: Yes non working snippet along with error trace

Comment: I have updated my question. Unfortunately Mahesh I cannot add the snippet in the comments, too long. Also I will update the error trace too.

Comment: is `wizard.excel.report.file`  a TransientModel from the error odoo trying to call fields_view_get of the model that return the structur of the view but the object is None not the model instance?

Answer (score 0):

1. can you try clear cache of browser
2. can you switch browser (if using crome then try with Firefox and if using FF then switch to crome and check) and after switch check if it works on first browser too
3. ensure you have imported packages correctly